# Python Pandas not using names field as it once did

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I have a short script that's a reduction of my application written using `"pandas>=0.25.3"` which has been upgraded to `"pandas==1.1.5"` the latest version of our code. In this version of Pandas, the default engine does not parse xlsx so we've added the `engine="openpyxl"`. However, there's a new issue. The `read_excel` no longer seems to respect the `names` argument and has strange behavior.

```
import pandas

filename = "... .xlsx"

names = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

data_frame = pandas.read_excel(
    filename,
    header=None,
    names=names,
    engine="openpyxl",
    skiprows=3,
    sheet_name=0,
)
print(data_frame.iloc[3])
```

Running the script with the new Pandas I get this output:

```
foo   NaN
bar   NaN
baz   NaN
Name: (FxK2,SMin, 2066.125), dtype: float64
```

But previously in pandas-0.25.3 parsing with the xlrd engine by default I got what I expected which was this:

```
foo   FxK2
bar   SMin
baz   2066.125
```

The `names` field gave names to the columns and then I could reference `data_frame.iloc[0].baz` and get `2066.125`. Now for some reason, then entire thing ends up in the optional name field for the data frame.

How can I get the behavior I was used to and is this potentially a bug or just new interface I'm not used to? The pandas-1.1.5 certainly seem to reference the `names` argument in the same way as I was used to using it.

Comment: Why not `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', ...)`?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Same behavior for both. Just a relic of how it was originally written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** (after comment threads):

I got the same problem for the second excel file when using `engine='openpyxl'`. When reading with `engine='xlrd'` I didn't get the problem, though. But it's probably a version-related issue with `xlrd`, since I'm using an older version '1.2.0' (currently it's 2.0.1), and there's a big warning in [xlrd docummentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) saying it no longer read anything other than .xls files.

Therefore, as we discussed in the comments, a possible work-around to use `engine='openpyxl'` is to specify the columns with `usecols=range(3)`, although it requires a previous knowledge of the columns in the file. The issue might be at some hiding formatting/styling/etc in those "empty" cells.

For example, in the same problematic file, if I select and copy the cells with values to another Sheet (Sheet1) in the same file, and read it with:

```
pd.read_excel('redux2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, names=['foo','bar','baz'], engine='openpyxl', skiprows=1)
```

then it works as expected.

---

**Original Answer:**

It's working as expected for me. Probably it's something with your data. Try the following code. If it works, then you know it's something with your data, not pandas.

**Sample data**

```
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': list(string.ascii_letters[:10]),
    'col2': list(string.ascii_letters[10:20]),
    'col3': range(1,11)
})

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
print(df)
```

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    k     1
1    b    l     2
2    c    m     3
3    d    n     4
4    e    o     5
5    f    p     6
6    g    q     7
7    h    r     8
8    i    s     9
9    j    t    10
```

**Testing**

```py
filename = 'file.xlsx'
names = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

data_frame = pd.read_excel(
    filename,
    header=None,
    names=names,
    engine="openpyxl",
    skiprows=3,
    sheet_name=0,
)

print(data_frame.iloc[3])
```

```
foo    f
bar    p
baz    6
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

---

Note: My pandas version is '1.1.5' as well.

Comment: That script works fine. I know it's an issue with the formatting of the Excel sheet. But it used to work in the old engine just fine. These are two files. redux1 works, redux2 is broken using the same code. But I would expect them to both work. Problem is I get my input in the form that redux2 was reduced from so I need to parse that. https://filebin.net/u7ugke2n5864gkwu

Comment: @mmachenry `pd.read_excel('redux2.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['foo','bar','baz'])` worked fine for me. If I replace `'redux2.xlsx'` by `'redux1.xlsx'`, it also works.

Comment: import pandas
print(pandas.read_excel("redux1.xlsx", header = None, names = ["foo","bar","baz"], engine = "openpyxl", skiprows=1))
print(pandas.read_excel("redux2.xlsx", header = None, names = ["foo","bar","baz"], engine = "openpyxl", skiprows=1))

Comment: That script run on those two files shows that that script with pandas-1.1.5, for me, is giving the foo,bar,baz header names to the right-most columns of the excel spreadsheet which are actually about 10 columns to the right and empty for a while. Do you get the same?

Comment: I got the same error now! It happens when we use `engine="openpyxl"` for the 'redux2.xlsx' file. It doesn't happen with `engine="xlrd"`, though. Weird.

Comment: Yes. Great that we're on the same page now. For engine xlrd though I get "xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported" which is why I moved to openpyxl in the first place.

Comment: A possible working-around for this is to use `usecols=range(3)`. It works, but it requires knowing how many columns there are beforehand...

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Hm... I wonder if this is a bug in openpyxl though.

Comment: It might be... You may consider raising an issue in their GitHub repository.

Comment: I'll do that. I'll give you the check mark for correct answer. Thanks for the help. I think the answer might best serve the community if you update it a tad with the result of this comment thread. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: Thanks @mmachenry. I've updated the answer, please take a lookt at it. I think there're some hidden elements retrieved by `openpyxl` that produces such weird pattern.